# clang sanitizer callback on error

Tags: c++, sanitizer

Is it possible to set some sort of a callback, which will be called when clang sanitizers find an error? I need to print some useful information, such as - test name.

P.S. Tests are kept/stored as XML files, not in C++, that is why stack trace won't tell me the failed test name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `__sanitizer_set_death_callback` and `__asan_set_error_report_callback` (declared in [asan_interface.h](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/include/sanitizer/asan_interface.h)).

Also as pointed by willir, it may be enough to just run with `ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=1`. This will cause Asan to call `abort` on error and many unit testing frameworks can then skip failing test and continue execution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'd like to add that it seems, in many cases just `ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error` environment variable is enough. It makes sanitizer call `abort` instead of `_exit` and so you can handle it. Most test frameworks already handle `abort`.